# How to calculate rank from multiple parameters to get best/trustworthy peer

Tags: ranking

How to calculate rank from multiple parameters ?

Parameters are bandwidth, delay, success ratio, these parameters values are used to determine the trustworthiness of a peer while accessing a service from a peer?.  My aim is to get the best peer, by using any ranking method ... which method can I use?

Comment: You're looking for parameter ranking. This has been answered before. Have a look at here: [Link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/11985/17937)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have data with rankings? If yes, you can build a linear regression model that predicts the score/rank given the 4 features. The feature weights will be learned from the training set. A positive weight will suggest that the feature adds positively to the rank (e.g bandwidth); a negative weight will suggest that increasing feature value will decrease the rank (e.g. delay).

You can use LIBSVM to fit a linear regression model or any other package for this task.